# Computer is stop working after I am running my code in python

Tags: python

```
def encode(line):
        el = [ord(c) for c in line]
        while len(el) is not 100:
            el.append(0)
        el = np.asarray(el).reshape(10,10)
        return el
with open("C:\\Users\\KIIT\\Desktop\\test.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[0:1]
        for line in lines:
            el = encode(line)
print(el)
```

For this code my computer is working fine with speed. But when I increase the size of the array if, the computer is stop working and I have to restart it.

the code for which it is not working:

```
def encode(line):
        el = [ord(c) for c in line]
        while len(el) is not 784:
            el.append(0)
        el = np.asarray(el).reshape(28,28)
        return el
with open("C:\\Users\\KIIT\\Desktop\\test.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[0:1]
        for line in lines:
            el = encode(line)
print(el)
```

Comment: `is not` is not how you write an inequality check.

Comment: Of course the while loop is pointless anyway; since you are using numpy you can just do `np.zeros(784)`.

Comment: _do not use `is` to compare integers or whatever else except `None`_. I hope python 4 will _remove_ this keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling foul of the integer cache in Python. `is not` is not the way to test for equality of integers. However, it *will* work for values between -5 and 256 because Python maintains a cache of objects for these values.

Change:
`while len(el) is not 784:`

To:
`while len(el) < 784:`

Comment: not 156, 256...

Comment: Not had my cup of tea to wake up this morning :)

Comment: that or fat fingers :)